# Python: Dynamically calling Method in separate script

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a project to control a 6 legged robot. I've got my scripts set up for the individual joint control and it's working fine. I have individual scripts for the joint controllers for each leg, leg_1_joint_control, leg_2_joint_control etc ..., all of these scripts have 3 PID controllers for the motors on each leg called PID1, PID2 & PID3. What I want to do is dynamically call my PID1,2&3 methods in my leg_'leg_no'_joint_control.py script (where 'leg_no' is the leg number [1 - 6]) without having to write a separate case for each leg.

Here's an ideal snippet of my leg control code to try and explain:

```
import leg_1_joint_control
import leg_2_joint_control
import leg_3_joint_control
...

def leg(args, leg_no):
    ...
    e1[t] = leg_'leg_no'_joint_control.PID1(args)
    ...
```

and my leg_'leg_no'_joint_control script

```
...
def PID1(args):
    ...
    return ek
```

So what I want to do is when I change the leg_no variable, I want to call PID1 in the scripts for the relevant leg. is this possible?
I've tried methods such as getattr() but have had no success.

Comment: Are the legs so different that you need three different scripts to control them? A single control class with one instance per leg seems simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Do not try to use dynamic names for variables it will cause headaches to develop and nightmares to maintain. Just use an array :

```
import leg_1_joint_control
import leg_2_joint_control
import leg_3_joint_control
...

legs_joint_control = [ leg_1_joint_control, leg_2_joint_control, ... ]

def leg(args, leg_no):
    ...
    e1[t] = legs_joint_control[leg_no].PID1(args)
    ...
```

Comment: Cheers! this has solved it. can this also be done for the PID1, 2 & 3?
eg.
pid = [PID1, PID2, PID3]

for i in (0, 3):
    ... = legs_joint_control[leg_no].pid[i](args)